# username and password not correct on trying to sign in - symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a little symfony app that handles signin and signout. Everything seems perfect but when I try to sign in to the app it keeps telling username/password not correct. This is my attempt

In the parameters.yml file I have this for the database connection

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: loginDb
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
```

I am using this in my UserController to check if username and password is correct

```
 if ($form->isValid()) {
........                    

                        $session->set("user", $user);

                        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("project_homepage"));
                    } else {
                        $session->getFlashBag()->add(
                                'message', "Username or password is incorrect."
                        );
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to login from the front end with the username and password as I have in my database but its not granting me access. This looks weird to me. What could be wrong. Thanks for assistance received

Comment: How is this failing? is the user found after executing the query? has the session been started?

Comment: yes the session has been started. after starging the server on trying to login it tells me incorrect credentials

Comment: `var_dump($user)` before `if ($user) {`.. is the user found ?

Comment: my best guess is the password you are passing into the query is wrong. Depending on how you set up your users, the encrypted password is not just sha1. If you use the symfony security, then the password would be set for the query by following https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html

Comment: @Rooneyl you are right sir! I removed the sha1 it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is the password you are passing into the query is wrong.

Depending on how you set up your users, the encrypted password is not just sha1. If you use the symfony security, then the password would be set for the query using the [encoder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html)

Comment: but u may need to use sha1 converter should incase u are a little bit not sure